# How do I find the sum of sizes of all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, terminal, directory

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04. How do I find the total size of all files in a directory? Accuracy is important here. I was previously using:

```
du -b
```

However, upon checking, it was giving me a value that is larger than the sum of all file sizes in the folder. Is there a different command I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -c%s {} + \
  | tr '\n' + 
  echo 0
) | bc
```

- `find` with `-maxdepth 1` doesn't descent into subdirectories. `-type f` only lists files. `-exec` runs the command for all the files, `stat -c%s` shows the size of each file.
- `tr` replaces each newline with a `+`
- `echo 0` puts a 0 at the end so there's no trailing `+`
- `bc` works as a calculator, it outputs the sum